# How to graph multiply imputation survey data

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, imputation

I'm working with Federal Reserve Survey of Consumer Finances (SCF) data, which expands the ~6500 actual observed responses into ~29,000 entries through multiple imputation. I'm able to generate summary statistics (counts, means, quantiles, etc.) using scf_MIcombine in the lodown package, but I'm having a lot of trouble representing it visually. The functions that account for multiple imputation tend to spit out svyimputationlist objects, which are challenging to cast into objects that ggplot can understand.

For example:

```
scf_design <- 
  svrepdesign( 
    weights = ~wgt , 
    repweights = scf_rw[ , -1 ] , 
    data = imputationList( scf_imp ) , 
    scale = 1 ,
    rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
    mse = FALSE ,
    type = "other" ,
    combined.weights = TRUE
  )
scf_design_work <- subset(scf_design, age>24 & age<65)
tab_knolLIT <- scf_MIcombine(with(svytable(~finlit+knowlcat, design = subset(scf_design_work,     finlit!=0))))
```

`#Error in UseMethod("svytable", design) :  no applicable method for 'svytable' applied to an object of class "svyimputationList"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score -1):

To graph multiply imputed survey data, you can use the mi or mice packages in R. Both packages offer functions for creating graphs based on multiply imputed data. Here is a step by step process:

1. Combine the multiple imputed data using *pool()* or *complete()*
   functions in the mi or mice package respectively.
2. Use ggplot2 to create visualizations. The ggplot2 library is
   powerful and flexible, allowing you to create a wide range of
   visualizations.
3. Use *mi_boxplot()* or *mi_histogram()* to create box plots or histograms for each variable. These functions take multiply imputed data as input and automatically handle the uncertainty introduced by the multiple imputations.
4. Use *mi_qqplot()* to create a quantile-quantile plot, which can help
   you to assess whether the distribution of the data is normal.
5. Use *mi_scatterplot()* to create a scatterplot matrix, which can help
   you visualize the relationship between multiple variables.

Note that it is important to account for the uncertainty introduced by multiple imputation when interpreting results, as the estimates and standard errors may be different than if a single imputed dataset was used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).